# Default value for Hive script parameter

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm wanting to use a default value for a parameter if it has not been set

e.g. for `hive -d param1=2014-06-20`

I can retrieve the value, i.e.

```
hive> select '${param1}';
OK
2014-06-20
```

but for a variable which hasn't been set the result is

```
hive> select '${param2}';
OK
${param2}
```

I would have expected null, etc

Ultimately I want to use a default value for a parameter if it hasn't been passed in, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM test_table t
WHERE t.date < COALESCE(${param1}, CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a direct documented way to carry this out but there the parameter value can be tested and a default returned if the value equals the name. i.e.

```
hive> select if(locate('${par', '${param2}')==0, '${param2}', CURRENT_DATE);
OK
2018-03-09
```